# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED in Ionic

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

> I got one error when I try to start new app in ionic.i'm using proxy to access to internet.my IP address is 172.16.30.20 and port number is 8080

```
D:\MyApp>ionic start diary1 tabs
Creating Ionic app in folder D:\MyApp\diary1 based on tabs project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error Initializing app:  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)

connect ECONNREFUSED (CLI v1.6.1)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.12.7
```

Comment: Can you try it without the proxy? Chances are that's your problem.

Comment: i use college network.so proxy usage is inevitable.is there a way to config with proxy?

Comment: Can you try it with localhost instead?

Comment: thing is I can't download ionic project using "ionic start diary1 tabs" command through proxy.I think there is a problem with node.js and proxy .

Comment: Can you go find a different network that doesn't have a proxy?

Comment: I found solution for that.We should use Nodejs command prompt for all configurations and commands.

Comment: @HRCJ what was the configuration that help you?? Should be nice that you post your solution, that could help other people. Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped me solve it.

http://manjeshpv.com/ionic-start-behind-the-proxy-on-windows-commandline/

I also work behind a proxy and want to use Cmder to do the job, so this worked well. The solution is quite out-dated as the request.js changed but just insert that before the part:

```
 if(!self.hasOwnProperty('proxy')) {
self.proxy = getProxyFromURI(self.uri)
```

}